# Parrot OS installer error "Command 'grub-install --target=i386-pc --recheck --force /dev/sdb' returned non-zero exit status 1"

Tags: grub2, system-installation, boot-loader, parrotsec

I encountered some errors when installing the Parrot sec OS 5.2.
This is the error message provided by the installer:

[image]

My computer supports UEFI mode and BIOS mode, and I have tried to use Rufus and BalenaEtcher USB flash disk burning software, and I have also tried MBR mode and UEFI mode, and I have also tried to install USB flash disk in GPT format and MBR format.

However, these operations have no effect. The error prompt still pops up. This makes it impossible for me to install this system.
After this error prompt pops up, I can't mount this partition in Ubuntu system.

If this is due to the problem of python code in this installation program, please tell me how to solve it (I am able to write python code, not a novice). If this problem has nothing to do with python code, please tell me how to handle it correctly.

Comment: My motherboard BIOS is a relatively old BIOS. It was produced in 2012 and cannot be upgraded. It also seems that I can't find a way to set up UEFI or BIOS mode separately.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem myself. If you can see my question, please refer to my solution carefully.
Confirm whether your computer supports UEFI mode. If you have failed to install Parrot Sec OS several times before, and there is no obvious word "UEFI mode" in your BIOS, then your BIOS does not fully support UEFI mode or does not support UEFI mode at all.
At this time, all you can do is find a motherboard or other computer that supports UEFI mode, insert the hard disk that you want to install Parrot Sec OS into the computer that supports UEFI mode, and then run the installation program again.
You may get a prompt in the last step to the effect that "the program returns timeout". Don't care about it. After the complete installation, remove the installation media, restart the computer, and view it in the BIOS.
At this time, you will be surprised to find that Parrot's Grub boot program has loaded Parrot normally, and you can use Parrot Sec OS happily.

If you still fail to install, please check the following problems:

1. Is the hard disk in GPT format? If not, please change to GPT format.
2. Is the USB flash disk (installation media) in GPT format? If not, please change to GPT format.
3. Is the installation media written to the USB flash drive correctly? If not, please use professional burning software such as Rufus or Balena Etcher.
4. Enable UEFI mode in the BIOS that supports UEFI, and set the USB flash disk as the first boot item.
5. Click "install" on the desktop to start installing the system and select the correct location to install.
6. Please try not to let the computer turn off the screen.